# How to get Rcpp and BH (Boost headers) working with regex_replace for Windows build

Tags: r, boost, rcpp

I'm using the excellent Rcpp project to implement some faster text processing in R, but cannot get the package to build correctly under Windows.  (It builds fine under OS X and Linux.)  I am using Rcpp, and the BH header packages.  I can get the example at http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/boost-regular-expressions/ and I can get the code below to build on every platform except Windows.

To isolate my problem I removed it from my larger package, and put it into a simple package so that it can be installed using `devtools::install_github("kbenoit/boostTest")`.

The files are:

`Makevars.win`:

```
PKG_LIBS = -lboost_regex
```

`src/clean.cpp`:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <string>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]

const boost::regex re_digits("[[:digit:]]");
const boost::regex re_punct("[[:punct:]]");
const std::string space0("");

std::string removeDigits(const std::string& s) {
    return boost::regex_replace(s, re_digits, space0, boost::match_default | boost::format_sed);
}

std::string removePunct(const std::string& s) {
    return boost::regex_replace(s, re_punct, space0, boost::match_default | boost::format_sed);
}


// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::DataFrame cleanCpp(std::vector<std::string> str) {
    int n = str.size();
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        str[i] = removeDigits(str[i]);
        str[i] = removePunct(str[i]);
    }
    return Rcpp::DataFrame::create (Rcpp::Named("text") = str);
}
```

and `cleanC.R` is exported as:

```
cleanC <- function(x) as.character(cleanCpp(x)[, 1])
```

(I did this because I am so new to Rcpp that I could not figure out how to return a CharacterVector, but could get the Rcpp::DataFrame return type working by following the boost-regular-expressions example linked above.

In my `DESCRIPTION` file I have:

```
LinkingTo: Rcpp,BH
```

The problem is that when I build the package using `devtools::build_win()`, it fails, even though it builds fine on Linux and OS X.  The output can be seen here:

```
* installing *source* package 'boostTest' ...
** libs

*** arch - i386
g++  -I"D:/RCompile/recent/R-3.1.3/include"            -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/lib/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/lib/3.1/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/lib/3.1/BH/include" -I"d:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local320/include"     -O3 -Wall  -mtune=core2            -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++  -I"D:/RCompile/recent/R-3.1.3/include"            -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/lib/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/lib/3.1/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/lib/3.1/BH/include" -I"d:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local320/include"     -O3 -Wall  -mtune=core2            -c clean.cpp -o clean.o
g++ -shared -s -static-libgcc -o boostTest.dll tmp.def RcppExports.o clean.o -lboost_regex -Ld:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local320/lib/i386 -Ld:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local320/lib -LD:/RCompile/recent/R-3.1.3/bin/i386 -lR
d:/compiler/gcc-4.6.3/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lboost_regex
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
no DLL was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'boostTest'
* removing 'd:/RCompile/CRANguest/R-release/lib/boostTest'
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: This linker error `[...] cannot find -lboost_regex [...] collect2: ld returned 1 exit status` usually means that you haven't given the compiler the correct library directory - in this case, the directory that contains `libboost_regex.so`, etc... For example, my boost library files are stored in `/usr/lib64`, so when I compile something that uses `<boost/regex.hpp>` , I pass to g++ (among other flags) `-L/usr/lib64` and `-lboost_regex`. I don't have a direct solution for you off hand, but you might start by into how to specify this `-L` flag for your situation.

Comment: Thanks for that, but my problem is exactly that I am not sure where the standard C++ boost libraries are located on the Windows machine that builds packages for CRAN. As mentioned above, I tried `-lboost_regex` in the `Makevars.win` file, and now I have also tried `-L/usr/lib64` but that did not work either.

Comment: Are you sure you _have_ this boost library on your Windows computer?  If so, where?  Use that location in `-L...`; the `-L/use/lib64` is unlikely _to even exist_ on your Windows box.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I am trying to find out, since it's not *my* windows system, but rather the one from the Windows system that builds packages on CRAN.  The page http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/ThirdPartySoftware.html indicates that BOOSTLIB is available but I am not sure how to specify the appropriate linking library in Makevars.win. Dirk, is there not a solution through the BH package? The source on r-forge seems for BH has https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/BH/inst/include/boost/regex/v4/?root=boostheaders but I am unsure how to include or link them. Thanks!